# Is Chat-GPT3 using our main site data?

Tags: discussion

Recently Chat-GPT is becoming popular as it is a potential chatbot. It is said to be trained over the internet and the documentation does not contain any specific information on sites it has been trained on.

I want to know from the users of the chatbot to analyze by asking questions whether it has been trained on our site or not.

Did anyone do such analysis and drawn conclusion from that?

Comment: It is very unlikely that Char-GPT will be suited for our website. Even if it does, I don't expect it to state anything outside Wikipedia. Hindu religion is a rather under-researched & unmoderated field in the digital platform.